# How to make virtual time pass in a test in Cats Effect 3?

Tags: scala, automated-tests, cats-effect

I am trying to convert [Mules](https://github.com/davenverse/mules) to Cats Effect 3 (CE3). Since it is a caching library, in its tests it needs (virtual) time to pass to test whether items will be expired. It is currently making fairly heavy use of [`cats.effect.laws.util.TestContext`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/v2.5.1/laws/shared/src/main/scala/cats/effect/laws/util/TestContext.scala), which allows advancing the virtual clock without actually sleeping via [`tick`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/v2.5.1/laws/shared/src/main/scala/cats/effect/laws/util/TestContext.scala#L293). `TestContext` does not (as far as I have been able to discover) exist in CE3, but I am always loathe to puts [`sleep`](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/api/3.x/cats/effect/kernel/GenTemporal.html#sleep(time:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration):F%5BUnit%5D) calls into a test. Rolling my own `IO` for this specific case though is a daunting prospect; surely this is a more general problem people have. I was not able to find a reference to `TestContext` in the [migration guide](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/migration-guide), however.

Is there a known upgrade path for this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by Victor in comments about v3.3.0, this version is released about a day ago and you can see examples for virtual time in [Mocking time](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/core/test-runtime#mocking-time) paragraph in docs

Answer (score 6):

With some help from Chris Davenport on Discord, I found that [`TestContext`](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/api/3.x/cats/effect/kernel/testkit/TestContext.html) is still there, but has been moved from `cats.effect.laws.util` to `cats.effect.kernel.testkit`. It lives in its own project and artifact, so you will need to add a dependency (SBT syntax):

```
    "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect-kernel-testkit" % catsEffectV % Test,
```

Also if you were not using anything else from the `laws` package than you will want to remove that dependency, which would look something like:

```
    "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect-laws"           % catsEffectV % Test,
```

Presumably this is why they moved it: because it is not specific to laws.

---

However, I was not successful in getting virtual time to pass in my tests with this, and have sadly brute-forced it with `IO.sleep`s for now. :/

Comment: Sadly, `TestContext` doc seems outdated for 3.x CE -- it has no `timer` method no more (timer is replaced with `Temporal`, per docs). I'm new to CE, so wondering which API could be used here.

Comment: Also, https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/issues/2220
Sadly, this is scheduled for 3.3.0